# C# MVC Facebook application does not work in iPad Facebook application

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, ipad, asp.net-mvc-4

I've written a Facebook application using Microsoft's ASP.NET MVC template.  Works great from the browser on IE, Android's browser and will even work in Safari.
Inside the Android Facebook application clicking on the link to my application bounces you out to the web browser and everything is good to go.  On an iPhone or iPad going to my application works fine from inside Safari.  But if you run the iPhone or iPad Facebook application you get an error.  Across the top it says 'Error' and the details say "An error occurred. Please try again later."

I've search the SDK docs and googled around but I've not found anything that tells me what to do. Did I miss a setting for my application?  Is there some special cookie I need?  Do I need to go leave my wallet at Steve Job's grave?
Any help would be appreciated.